# Difference of GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT and glFlush in a multi context / multi thread scenario

Tags: opengl-es

I have a multithreaded scenario with a foreground OpenGL context for rendering and a background OpenGL context for uploading with context resource sharing activated. After the background thread has issued glBufferData it creates a fence with glFenceSync and then calls glClientWaitSync with GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT set. However, this doesn't seem to guarantee a flush as the main thread waits forever for the fence to be signaled. Only replacing glClientWaitSync with glFlush will do the job.

Can someone tell me why?

C++, Linux, GLES 3.2

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me why?

Most probable answer is that the driver is buggy. According to the spec `GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT` should be equivalent to inserting a `glFlush()`, so if it isn't it sounds like an implementation issue.